# Prove that every subspace of $V$ invariant under $T$ has even dimension.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

> Suppose that $V$ is  a real vector space and $T:V\to V$ is a linear operator having no eigen values.
>
> Prove that every subspace of $V$ invariant under $T$ has even dimension.

**Attempt**: If $V$ has dimension odd so the characteristic polynomial of $T$ also has odd degree and hence has a real root which is false

Hence $\dim V$= even.

But that's not helping me here,I should deal with invariant subspace  here.But how should I do it?

Comment: Let $W$ be an invariant subspace. What do you know about $T\lvert_W \colon W \to W$?

Comment: I don't get what we know about $T|_W$?

Answer (score 2):

If $W$ is invariant by $T$, $T_{\mid W}$ , the restriction of $T$ to $W$ does not have real eigenvalues too. Suppose that its dimension is odd, the degree of the characteristic polynomial $P_W$  of $T_{\mid W}$ is odd, so it  has a real root, contradiction, since a root of $P_W$ is an eigenvalue.

Write $P_W=a_0+a_1x+..+a_nx^n$, if $a_n>0$ $lim_{x\rightarrow-\infty}P_W(x)=-\infty$ and $lim_{x\rightarrow+\infty}P_W(x)=+\infty$ or the converse if $a_n<0$. So IVT theorem implies there exists $x$ such that $P_W(x)=0$.

Comment: Why it does not have real eigen values?

Comment: if $n$ is the degree of $P_W$ and $a_n>0$ $lim_{x\rightarrow-\infty}P_W(x)=-\infty$ and $lim_{x\rightarrow+\infty}P_W(x)=+\infty$ or the converse if $a_n<0$.